# eV and redox potential

Tags: redox, energy

I am trying to estimate the redox potential of an excited state as described in [this reference](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo202538x).

The paper says:

> The reduction potentials associated with the excited states
>   cannot be directly measured and are typically calculated from
>   known cyclic voltammetry (CV) and spectroscopic data. As
>   an approximation, the excited-state potentials of a catalyst are
>   related to its ground state potentials and its zero−zero excitation energy ($E_{0,0}$). $E_{0,0}$ can be estimated by the difference in
>   energy between *PC $^3$MLCT$_1$ and PC $^1$A$_1$ and can be approximated by the maximum emission of the catalyst (Figure 2). As an example, the emission maximum for $\ce{Ru(bpy)3Cl2}$ in MeCN
>   has been measured to be $\pu{615 nm}$ at room temperature and $\pu{582
> nm}$ at $\pu{77 K}$ in a frozen MeOH/EtOH mixture. This corresponds
>   to an $E_{0,0}$ value of $\pu{2.02 eV}$ at room temperature and $\pu{2.13 eV}$ at $\pu{77 K}$. Given the ground-state reduction potentials, the excited-state
>   reduction potentials can be calculated as shown in Figure 4.

Then Figure 4 shows the calculation for the room temperature case:

$\ce{Ru(bpy)3^{3+} + e^- -> \text{*}Ru(bpy)3^{2+}}$

$E_{red} = \pu{1.26 V} - \pu{2.02 V} = \pu{-0.76 V}$

**My question is:** Why is it valid to use the $\pu{2.02 eV}$ from the spectroscopic measurement as $\pu{2.02 V}$ in the redox potential calculation?

From my understanding, $\pu{2.02 eV}$ is the energy between the ground state and the excited state, but these are units of energy, not potential, so I'm having a hard time seeing how can this calculation be done.

Comment: E = qV fixes the dimensions

Comment: @Alchimista I'm not sure how this answers the question

Comment: @ralk912, I feel the calculation cannot be that trivial. In this case one would write to the corresponding author if he can tell you. I dislike such papers which do not bother to mention the details of their obscure calculations. Their reference 21, for this method from 1970, never bothers to make a clear connection between E(00) and the reduction potential.

Comment: "but these are units of energy, not potential, so I'm having a hard time seeing how can this calculation be done" I refer to what seems the question to me, by commenting on dimension discrepancy.

Comment: It boils down to allocate somewhere in absolute energy scale the levels involved. One assume the first level accessed by spectroscopy to be the one where the electron is received upon reduction. For determining where the el.chem. potential is see https://almantaspivrikas.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-convert-redox-potential-vs-nhe_15.html?m=1 for instance. Obviously this is prone to multiple error sources. But it does not seem related to the core question, which is just about dimensions discrepancy. Potential times electron charge gives energy. I must say that most of your formula are invisible

Comment: ....to me. That's why I am commenting on the only point I have clear.